# why need hidden value for passing model in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Let's say I have a City table in SQL server.
This is the HomeController:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SampleDBContex db = new SampleDBContex();
        return View(db.Cities);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public string Index(IEnumerable<City> cities)
    {
        if (cities.Count(x => x.IsSelected) == 0)
        {
            return "You didn't select city";
        }
        else
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("You selected -");
            foreach (City city in cities)
            {
                if (city.IsSelected)
                {
                    sb.Append(city.Name + ", ");
                }
            }
            sb.Remove(sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(","), 1);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

    }

}
```

and this is index view (get method):

```
@model IEnumerable<Part38MVCCheckBoxList.Models.City>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

and this is the editor template:

```
@model Part38MVCCheckBoxList.Models.City

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)



@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
```

I don't understand why do we need to use @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name), otherwise it couldn't display city name.I think we pass the model IEnumerable so we should have cityname existed already when we retrieve them from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a hiddenfor because HTTP messaging is stateless, so if you'd get an object from a controller it will have the complete object on your page but if you'd send everything back except your Name and Id variable as inputs with values on your form it will be lost.

Your controller will only retain it as long as it's needed and after your HttpGet answer from the controller the controller is done and it will no longer retain that value.

I too feel it's counter intuitive, but this is how HTTP protocol is built.

Comment: but don't we just pass a city instance/object to the postback view, the object should have everything we need? just like we have a form to create a new city then we pass it like ActionResult Index(City city), so city object will have everything including name,id etc

Comment: In the Edit action you want to edit a particular entity, so the controller needs to know which entity to map on.

The docs say:
`The ASP.NET MVC model binder takes the posted form values and creates a Movie object that's passed as the movie parameter.`

[See docs here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view)

Answer (score 0):

We taken hidden properties because on controller side we need then in order to filter something on backend or may be those property may form keys while querying database . So entirely depends on your design and controller needs .you can choose to remove then if you dont need .

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless so controller will not have the data once it is sent to the client as part of the model to the view.

It also not necessary and must to create hidden controls for each of the model properties in the view.

The general rule is the value which needs to be posted back as part of the model should be rendered in the HTML as an input (text, password, hidden, checkbox etc.).

The hidden controls are created only for the properties which should be sent back to POST action in the controller as part of the model.

If the property values is just to be displayed, creating label for it or rendering it in the span would be good enough.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke but don't we just pass a city instance/object to the postback view, the object should have everything we need? just like we have a form to create a new city then we pass it like ActionResult Index(City city), so city object will have everything including name,id etc

Comment: @grooveline, Its not my answer :) - I just edited it

Comment: But to further explain what is happening - your client makes a request to your POST method. The `DefaultModelBinder` then initializes a new instance of the collection (the parameter in your `Index()` method), and the reads the values from the request (the name/value pairs from the form control) and initializes sets the values of the each `City` object. If you do not post a value for `Name`, then its not in the request, so it cannot be set (and will be `null`)